# Run python script with gdb with alias

Tags: gdb, gdb-python

When I want to run python into gdb I using

`source /tmp/gdb/tmp/parser.py`

1. Can I set an alias  so in the next time I want to call this script I use only `parser.py` or `parser` (without setting the script into working directory
2. How can I pass args to script ? `source /tmp/gdb/tmp/parser.py <args1>`  doesn't work

Comment: Instead of sourcing the script multiple times, you could create a function in the script, source it one time, and call the function as many times as you want (with arguments).

Answer (score 0):

These should have been asked as two separate questions, really. But:

1. Execute command `dir /tmp/gdb/tmp/`, after that you should be able to run script as `source parser.py`
2. You can't when you are sourcing a script. Rewrite script so that it attaches itself as GDB command via class inheriting from `gdb.Command`. The command can accept arguments. And you will save on typing `source ...` too.